# DrawText DT_CALCRECT with DT_WORDBREAK

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I want to get dimensions, of printed text, to draw a bitmap after the text. When I use something like:

```
CRect rc2={ 0, 0, 0, 0 };
dc.DrawText(txt, &rc2, DT_CALCRECT);
```

everything is ok. But when I have long text lines, and want to use

```
dc.DrawText(txt, &rc2, DT_CALCRECT|DT_WORDBREAK);
```

rc2 returns 0,0,0,0. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: This is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawtext): *"Determines the width and height of the rectangle. If there are multiple lines of text, `DrawText` uses the width of the rectangle pointed to by the `lpRect` parameter and extends the base of the rectangle to bound the last line of text."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right margin has to be specified, and the problem solved.

```
int rightmarg=PrintDC.GetDeviceCaps(HORZRES);
r.right = rightmarg;
DrawText(dc, txt, txt.GetLength(), &r, DT_CALCRECT|DT_WORDBREAK|DT_WORD_ELLIPSIS|DT_NOPREFIX);
```